# ethereum ledger size

Tags: mining, blockchain

I don't understand quit well what are the requirements on the disk volume to run a full node of ethereum and what is its expected growth.

e.g. for now I have the following volume distribution across different ethereum folders on an ubuntu machine (listed only the biggest chunks):

```
16G ./.ethash
12G ./.ethereum
12G ./.ethereum/chaindata
```

what's exactly there (**.ethereum** and **./.ethereum/.chaindata** seem to have the same size)?

how much disk space does the mining activity require (that's the reason for space in the folder **./.ethash** or not?)?

**Edit:** additional info - content of **./ethash**
running the **ls -l** command there

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu       4096 Jul 24 07:22 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 ubuntu ubuntu       4096 Jul 23 18:16 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1409284744 Jul 24 07:43 full-R23-03b8bc47a10d1baa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1367339400 Jul 24 00:20 full-R23-1250db2965df18ca
```

You see big binary files.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs

Comment: it partly answers it. What's the reason behind the data in **.ethash**? Does mining requires so much space? (I'm running geth in basic mode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand quit well what are the requirements on the disk
>   volume to run a full node of ethereum and what is its expected growth.

See this previous thread: [What are the Ethereum disk space needs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs)

> 16G ./.ethash 12G ./.ethereum 12G ./.ethereum/chaindata what's exactly
>   there

The `chaindata` folder contians the downloaded copy of the blockchain.

> (.ethereum and ./.ethereum/.chaindata seem to have the same size)?

`.ethereum` is the parent to `chaindata`. The fact they're the same size just means that all/most of the data in `.ethereum` is also in `chaindata`.

> how much disk space does the mining activity require (that's the
>   reason for space in the folder ./.ethash or not?)?

The `.ethash` folder contains the [DAG](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/what-actually-is-a-dag), which is required for mining, and which should be around [1.5 GB](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/426/what-is-the-current-dag-size-when-do-we-expect-to-hit-gpu-limits?rq=1) at present. It's possible your 16 GB directory contains several older DAGs, though it's difficult to say without seeing the contents.

Comment: The disk volume usage is the result of 1 day of machine's existence, i.e. the old DAGs were downloaded in 1 day, is there an option to exlude them? would **geth --fast** exclude them?

Comment: What is the content of the `.ethash` directory?

Comment: I listed its content in the edit to the question.Basically, some huge binary files

Comment: Okay, they are both DAG files. The DAG is regenerated every 30,000 blocks (~100 hours). To make sure the transition from one DAG to the next is efficient, the next DAG is generated ahead of time, which is why you have 2 of them. I can't see why your first set of figures would be listing that directly as 16 GB, given the two DAGs only amount to ~2.8 GB (which is as expected).