# Unable to mine blocks in private Blockchain in VM

Tags: mining, miner

I am trying to run a test Ethereum blockchain and I was following this tutorial [How to create local multi-node private Ethereum network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49KK8MbMggQ). At around 25 minutes, the tutor shows how to mine. Till now, I have exactly followed his steps and have successfully replicated them on my system. However, at this stage, when I run the command `miner.start(1)`, it returns `null` instead of `true`.

Even on running `eth.mining` command, it shows `false`, indicating mining has not started yet. Neither is any DAG being created. I posed this same question to the tutor on his channel, but there doesn't seem to be any solution.

I am running geth CLI on a Ubuntu 16.04 VM allocating a 1 core CPU with RAM of 1 GB. I am not using the Mist Wallet to track ether or accounts. The JS console seems powerful enough for that. Is mining not taking place because of running of the instance on VM? Kindly help me out ASAP.

This is the genesis.json file content, just for reference.

> { "config": {
>
> "chainId": 0,
>    "homesteadBlock": 0,
>        "eip155Block": 0,
>         "eip158Block": 0 
>     },
>
> "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
>
> "timestamp": "0x00",
>
> "parentHash": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000$
>
> "extraData": "0x00",
>
> "gasLimit": "0x08000000",
>
> "difficulty": "0x0400",
>
> "mixhash": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000$
>
> "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
>
> "alloc" : 
>      {
>
> }
>
> }

Edit 1: Added JSON file content.

Edit 2 : Added RAM allocation in VM

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13745/miner-taking-a-long-time-to-start-on-private-network/17909#17909

Comment: Not a duplicate. The mining is not slow in my case, it just doesn't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> allocating a 1 core CPU with RAM of 1 GB

I'm sorry to inform you, that this is by far not enough. ;) You need at least(!) 4GB for mining, or things won't move. 4,5 GB is a better value, just to be sure. Also a bit more CPU power won't do any harm.

Comment: I get that. But, for such a lesser power, the mining should be incredibly slow, right? Why am I getting `null` when I go for `miner.start(1)`?

Comment: Hello again! Tried the same with 4GB RAM, but the problem still persists. `eth.mining` this time returned `true` but `miner.start(2)` still returns `null` and `eth.hashrate` and `eth.blockNumber` returns 0, two hours after starting the mining. The log also shows no indication of creating a DAG.

Comment: The arg in miner.start determines how many threads / cores to use. if you assigned only one core to your machine, miner.start(2) cannot work of course. So stick to just simply miner.start, that seems to work for you.

Comment: Simply `miner.start()` also returning `null`,  with `eth.mining` returning 'true', `eth.blockNumber` and `eth.hashrate` returning `0`.

Comment: If the genesis file is correct, I wonder now if there's a problem with the flags used to initiate the genesis file. I have made a shell script to  initiate the file and get into console as follows:
`geth --identity "$4"  --rpc --rpcport "$3" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "/home/argo/ethereum/$1" --port $2 --nodiscover  --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,miner" --networkid 1900 --nat "any" init "/home/argo/ethereum/genesis.json"`
I use different identities, RPCPort and Port for different node instances.
To get into the console, I replace `init "path/to/*.json` with `console>console.log`

Comment: Hi again! It seems resolved now. I created a new VM this time, with 4 GB RAM and single core. Although `miner.start()` is still returning `null`, it is now creating blocks and blockchains is now increasing.

However, I still don't understand the reason why miner.start() returns null. If this won't affect the performance of the blockchain, I will rather go ahead and mark it as solved.