# Am I mining? Which part of log has to do with it? (Geth)

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

I'm starting to mine on CPU with geth but am not sure,

Is something like that

`I0519 06:26:02.720818 ethash.go:291] Generating DAG: 67%`

Supposed to mean that I'm mining? Do I stop mining when generating DAG stops then?

Or is something like that:

`I0519 06:26:05.475875 core/blockchain.go:1001] imported 11 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 402 txs in 8.545847414s. #756963 [0ef146c0 / d65fca69]`

should tell me that I'm mining?

Why does mining sometimes stop with a long message looking like this
`goroutine 118 [IO wait, 8 minutes]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x7fc130005f40, 0x72, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:160 +0x59
net.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc4204395d0, 0x72, 0xc422d12dc0, 0xc4200101e0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x38
net.(*pollDesc).waitRead(0xc4204395d0, 0x1482c00, 0xc4200101e0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78 +0x34
net.(*netFD).accept(0xc420439570, 0x0, 0x14809c0, 0xc422d18020)
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:419 +0x238
net.(*TCPListener).accept(0xc42003e0a8, 0xc422d12e98, 0xc422d12e98, 0x418385)
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:132 +0x2e
net.(*TCPListener).Accept(0xc42003e0a8, 0xc422d1c000, 0x0, 0x2, 0xc4204d2000)
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/tcpsock.go:222 +0x49
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p.(*Server).listenLoop(0xc42045c300)
        /var/tmp/portage/net-p2p/go-ethereum-1.4.18/work/go-ethereum-1.4.18/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/server.go:579 +0x276
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p.(*Server).startListening
        /var/tmp/portage/net-p2p/go-ethereum-1.4.18/work/go-ethereum-1.4.18/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/server.go:382 +0x156`

Is it an error or is it good and I have mined something?

I'm new and unfortunately this is not described in the manual. The manual says to check everything in the console mode, but it doesn't work (answers 'undefined' on all interesting questions)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, mining does not start until the [DAG](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/what-actually-is-a-dag) is created. DAG generation could take a while depending on your hardware, there's options to speed it up and get mining more quickly. One option is pre-generating it on a faster machine, and then moving it to the mining node.

The block import line looks like you are syncing from the blockchain correctly. [You should wait](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/mining.html#the-algorithm) until the blockchain is synced before mining.

As for the goroutine trace, it's hard to say without seeing the code.