# Ethereum private network on docker

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, ubuntu, docker, ppa

I am trying to create a **private network on docker** such that each geth node in the network is run on a docker container.

I followed this git hub blog :https://gist.github.com/fishbullet/04fcc4f7af90ee9fa6f9de0b0aa325ab . I am able to create containers and run geth nodes but the nodes always show **hashrate=0**.It take a lot of time to mine even if the difficulty in the genesis file is set to very low value(0x10). I thought it is the geth version problem.Will it work if I downgrade geth to lower version ??

geth version:1.8.2
Ubuntu VM :16.04
OS: windows 7 (I am using docker tool box).
Can someone help me with this...

Comment: On which nodes are you trying to mine? 

The creation of the DAG https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/what-actually-is-a-dag is a very space and cpu consuming task. So, if the nodes you are deploying your network are not powerful, this task requires a lot of time. The dag does not depend on the difficulty as you can read in the yellow paper.

Answer (score 5):

We have written a Docker container to run a private Ethereum network that works with Remix and MetaMask. You can see the details on our [Dockerized Ethereum Private Testing Environment Compatible with MetaMask and Remix](https://blog.coinfabrik.com/dockerized-ethereum-private-testing-environment-compatible-with-metamask-and-remix/).