# Can I mine ethereum with a gtx 1060 3GB?

Tags: mining, ethminer

When I'm launching ethminer it return the following lines

[image: ethminer result]

and exit after `m 01:48:55 main     Speed 0,00 Mh/s gpu0 0,00 [A0] Time: 00:00`

Has my GPU enough memory?

Answer (score 1):

For mining Ethereum it is necessary to build a so called DAG.  [This post explains it](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/what-actually-is-a-dag).

Ethereum has AFAIK the highest demand to resources to mine amongst all currencies.

According to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/comments/6eatic/what_is_the_hash_rate_for_the_gtx_1060_3gb_like/) mining with your card might not work due to insufficient memory. Seems like you ran into that problem.